# Save Record with INSERTs - SAVE and 1 INSERT not working but rest work fine

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to create or save a record, and if the associated record exists within a secondary table, it only saves/updates the record on the form.  The INSERT statements work just fine, but I suck at referencing forms/subforms and I have a feeling it has something to do with these.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmdSave_Click_Err

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

If DCount("*", "[tblRegSR]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & [Forms]![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].Form![txtID]) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Requery
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Value = ""
    Me.txtComments.Value = ""
    MsgBox "Save Completed"
Else
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryInsertSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblFirstSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSecondSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblInflatorSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblHPSPGSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblOctoSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblComputerSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Requery
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Value = ""
    Me.txtComments.Value = ""
    MsgBox "Sub Tables Injected"
End If


cmdSave_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdSave_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdSave_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

I expect the process to check whether a record exists in `tblRegSR` that has a relationship to `tblWorkOrders` and the record matches the appropriate linked field (`[WorkOrderID]` in `tblRegSR` matches to `[ID]` in `tblWorkOrders`).  If the associated record does not exist in `tblRegSR` then create it along with the child tables (`tblFirstSR` and so on).  
Additionally, it's just not updating/saving the original record in `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`
 So I'm not entirely sure where it's causing problems.  It's not INSERT'ing into `tblWorkOrders` or `tblRegSR` but it is INSERT'ing into all other tables.  I'm sure once I figure the other two INSERTs out it'll the `IF` statement will work fine...I hope...

**EDIT BELOW:**
Here are a couple screenshots of the data types:
[tblWorkOrders Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSRzo.png)
[tblRegSR Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbcn9.png)
[Child Table Data Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTnDj.png)
[Picture of my table Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBAD0.png)

As for the count, I assume it's working because it's always completing the `ELSE` statement where it `INSERT` the rows into the child tables (`tblFirstSR`, etc.).  However, it is NOT INSERT'ing into `tblRegSR`, nor is it saving the record on the form (which is in `tblWorkOrders`).  Hopefully this answers your questions @Nathan_Sav - thank you!

**EDIT TWO:**
Here is an image of the Validation Rule Violation: 
[Validation Rule Violation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V0J8.png)

**EDIT THREE:**
I decided to just share the entire database.  Here is a link.[Work Order Database](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_T-G9fyYQYjH3-YBe4PXhbBDTKNmY3ce)

**EDIT FOUR (10 Jan 19):**
Here is the new code I'm using along with the code I'm using in my append query `qryInsertSR`

In `qryInsertSR` this is the SQL I'm using:
 
`INSERT INTO tblRegSR (WorkOrderID, CustomerID) 
VALUES (Forms![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].Form![txtID], 
        Forms![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].Form![Customer])`

Also, I've updated the code snippet above to reflect any changes I've made.

**EDIT FIVE (11 Jan 19):**
Here's an image of my object browser showing everything in the database.  Including sfrmWorkOrders.  
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyHjO.png)

Comment: What is happening?  Is the count what you expected, are any of the SQL lines running?  Can you show the data types for the fields of issue also

Comment: thanks for the reply - I updated the original question to hopefully answer your questions.  Also added some pictures of my tables and relationships.

Comment: What is the recordsource of the form is it built off a table?  Try removing `On Error GoTo cmdSave_Click_Err` and seeing if there is an error.

Comment: Same question. It appears you have a main form and subform. Is *frmWelcome* bound to any recordsource?

Comment: `frmWelcome` has several subforms but the one being used in this tab is `sfrmWorkOrders`.  I will attempt to remove the `Error GoTo` code and test it out.  The recordsource bound to the subform is `tblWorkOrders.`--EDIT--Removing Error GoTo didn't solve anything - I'm getting a validation rule violation now. Actually, that might have narrowed something down, but I don't have any idea what that is hah. Thanks everyone so far! –

Comment: Post details of the violation error to.

Comment: Added to original post - thank you! Also, @Parfait, `frmWelcome` itself is not bound to anything, but the subforms contained on the form are to different tables per subform.

Comment: Added a link for the database in case anyone wants to look at the entire thing.

Comment: You should probably be careful about assuming the max of the ID is the right one if you're working in a high transaction/multi-user environment. Maybe look at preallocating new ID's and storing it on the form for multiple inserts like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attempting to use form values in `DLookUp` and an SQL query, you must use pass values in as parameters or by concatenation. Unless using a saved query, form values need to be passed into needed SQL or `DLookUp` and not hard-coded with the string.

Otherwise, Access engine uses the literal value `'[Forms]![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].Form![txtID]'` which fails since it is not a number and uses unescaped, special characters. This may be reason for type conversion violation.

Therefore, adjust `DCount` as:

```
If DCount("*", "[tblRegSR]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & [Forms]![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].Form![txtID]) > 0 Then
        ...
```

And **save** your append query as an MS Access object. These types of queries can read form/report parameters or any object opened to screen:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblRegSR (WorkOrderID, CustomerID) 
VALUES (Forms![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].[Form]![txtID], 
        Forms![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].[Form]![Customer])
```

To be run in VBA as following (with no need to close it being an action query):

```vb
If DCount("*", "[tblRegSR]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & [Forms]![frmWelcome]![sfrmWorkOrders].[Form]![txtID]) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Save Completed"
Else
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True           ' REDUNDANT AS WARNINGS START AS TRUE
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblFirstSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSecondSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblInflatorSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblHPSPGSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblOctoSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblComputerSR (ServiceRecordID) SELECT Max(ID) FROM tblRegSR"
    MsgBox "Sub Tables Injected"
End If

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord     ' MOVE SAVE INSTANCE TO END
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
Me.lstWorkOrders.Requery
Me.lstWorkOrders.Value = ""
Me.txtComments.Value = ""
```

---

**Table Relationships**

With all that said, carefully think about your table relationships which causes referential integrity violations between parent and child tables depending on update. Specifically your workflow above attempts to update a child table **after** parent table record is saved. A primary key from parent must exist **before** foreign key in child. Above will populate *tblRegSR* only if its relationship to *tblWorkOrder* is broken.

[image: Table Relationships Image]

Comment: Second, I reviewed your database. Main issue comes down to your table relationships as explained above. The saved query will work and most of the VBA with re-order of lines. For VBA, the `DCount` evaluation must occur before record is saved and form record source `inner joins` parent and child table. I advise re-vamping your structure and UI workflow.

Comment: Consider creating a *tblRegSR* subform on *tblWorkOrder* main form (not as `inner join` for recordsource) and then populate child tables once *tblRegSR* record is created, even avoiding need of `Max(ID)` calls. For further assistance, try reading db design and Access forms tutorials/forums and/or reach out to specialized contractors on sites like UpWork.

Comment: I'll probably revamp this form because this has been such a nightmare trying to accomplish what I want to accomplish and you gave me some great ideas for changes.  The code you've provided and the suggestions to my table relationships have worked, except one issue I'm having.  The main table (`tblWorkOrder`) isn't being updated and the record isn't being saved.  Would it be because the *active* table is being changed from `tblWorkOrder` to the child tables during the `DCount ... Else` statement?  Everything else is finally working, though, so thank you!!!

Comment: I noticed that very same issue of inability to save records in that form. Maybe something else is going on behind the scenes like recordsource or a corrupt form. I do recommend starting over. Try to align the flow of your forms like the flow of your tables and its relationships. Always think which comes first in data entry. Glad to help where I can. Good luck!